# Set PHP include for 70% with CSS

Tags: php, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

On a page of our website we load a responsive php script with PHP include. The script is displayed too widely on laptops and monitors. What is the way to use CSS to set this width for e.g. 70%  (only laptops and monitors)?

The code is the following:

```
<div id="bestelling">
 <?php include"cwhoiscart.php"; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no responsive code from php, as it runs on serverside. Please check out for "Media Queries" in CSS to achieve this. Here is a helpful link: https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whatever is included: The included php code will be parsed as HTML code, which most likely also contains classes and IDs which enable you to apply CSS to them. So you have to find out which HTML elements you want to address and write according CSS for those, including media queries.